# Subsonic 2.1 : Way to ignore a column while generating code?

Tags: subsonic, code-generation

For some reason, a row named "rowguid" with a "uniqueidentifier" parameter was added to some tables on an already existing project. While regenerating the code, I found out that a method named "Insert(string Key)" was used, but doesn't exists anymore (it's now  Insert(string Key, Guid varRowguid).

**Is there a way to "ignore" a column while generating the code?**

Note : The default of this new "rowguid" column is the Sql server method newsequentialid()

**UPDATE :** I added a "new System.GUId()" as a second parameter but I'd like to not have to modify the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With subsonic 2.1, you can edit the templates that are used to generate the code. I've added a "IF" and checked the "rowguid"... if it's the case, just ignore it.